# Multiple title pages with unique authors and affiliations per page

Tags: titles

I am a novice in LaTeX and I started writing my thesis in overleaf.
The thesis is paper based, meaning that I will have a chapter called "Papers" which will include six manuscripts.

For that, I have made the structure I need in a main tex where I input the individual manuscript as follows:

```
\chapter{Papers}
\input{chapters/Papers/A}
\input{chapters/Papers/B}
\input{chapters/Papers/C}
```

The problem:
I want to have a title page for each of the papers. I have created the following which shows the title, authors and their affiliation as I want

[image].

```
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{flushleft}
  \textbf{\@title}

  \@author
\end{flushleft}\egroup
}
\makeatother

\title{My title} 

\author[1]{A alpha}
\author[2]{B beta}

\affil[1]{A university}
\affil[2]{Another university}

\date{}                     

\maketitle
```

However, when I need to use the same functions to create the title page for my second manuscript I get both the authors and affiliations from the first and the second paper printed the one after the other. I have read how `\maketitle` works and some tips on how to bypass it, but neither worked for me. I also tried the titling package which messed up the way I want the authors and their affiliations to look.

Any help will be much appreciated!